# Update beliefs after learning uncertain information

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Let's consider the following events:

- $W$: the ground is wet,
- $R$: it rained this morning.

If, a priori, I attribute probability $0.5$ to event $R$, after learning that $W$ is realized, I will modify my beliefs according to Bayes' theorem.

$$P(R\mid W)=\frac 12\frac{P(W\mid R)}{P(W)}=\frac 1{2P(W)}$$

However, if I am not sure that $W$ is realized (let's say $P(W)=\frac 45$), for example if I have been told that the ground is wet without having seen it myself, how do I update my belief in $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I am not sure that $W$ is realized (let's say $P(W)=\frac 45$), for example if I have been told that the ground is wet without having seen it myself, how do I update my belief in $R$?

You would need to condition on the information that you *do* have; e.g.,

- $J$: Joe says that the ground is wet.

Then the updated probability is expressed as $P(R|J)$:

$$\begin{align}P(R|J)
&=P(R|JW)P(W|J)+P(R|J\bar{W})P(\bar{W}|J)\tag{1}\\
&=P(R|W)P(W|J)+P(R|\bar{W})(1-P(W|J))\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$
where, by Bayes' Theorem,
$$\begin{align}P(R|W)
&={P(W|R)P(R)\over P(W|R)P(R)+P(W|\bar R)P(\bar R)}={1\over 1 + {P(W|\bar R) \over P(W|R)}{1-P(R)\over P(R)}}\tag{3}\\ \\[2ex]
P(R|\bar{W})
&=\cdots={1\over 1 + {1-P(W|\bar R) \over 1-P(W|R)}{1-P(R)\over P(R)}}\tag{4}
\end{align}$$
assuming all denominators are nonzero.

Thus, your initial assessment of $P(R)$ is updated by Joe's statement $(J)$, using only your assessment of the three probabilities $P(W|\bar R), P(W|R),$ and $P(W|J)$.

Notes:

- (1) is just the "[law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement)" for conditional probabilities. In the context of subjective probability, it is sometimes called "extending the conversation" to incorporate information not yet considered.
- (1)$\implies$(2) assuming that if $W$ is *given*, then Joe's statement that $W$ is true is irrelevant to one's degree of belief in $R$; i.e., $P(R|JW)=P(R|W),$ etc.

Comment: Wonderful! Could you explain what the P(R|JW) notation means? I suppose it is P(R|J and W)

Comment: @Blincer - Yes, if the [probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) is such that $J$ and $W$ are *sets*, then $JW$ denotes their *intersection* $J\cap W$. Equivalently, if the theory is such that $J$ and $W$ are logical *propositions*, then $JW$ denotes their *conjunction* $J\land W$, also written $J\  {\tt{ AND }}\ W.$